# Create a Rank column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to write a query that will return a product ranking by business units by total sales.
The expected columns should include the columns: Rank, Business units, product, sales. I'm able to all columns except I don't understand how to create a new "Rank" Column.

This is the data I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE product_sales
(order_line_item_id bigint,
Business_unit varchar(255),
product_name varchar(255),
sales bigint);

INSERT INTO product_sales VALUES
(1, 'Goop Skincare', 'Goop Glow', 100),
(2, 'Goop Skincare', 'Peel Pads', 100),
(3, 'G Label', 'Puff Sleeve Sweatshirt', 200),
(4, 'G Label', 'Puff Sleeve Sweatshirt', 400),
(5, 'Goop Skincare', 'Peel Pads', 100),
(6, 'Goop Skincare', 'Goop Glow', 200),
(7, 'G Label', 'Puff Sleeve Sweatshirt', 100),
(8, 'Goop Skincare', 'G. Tox', 100),
(9, 'Goop Skincare', 'Goop Glow', 300),
(10, 'Goop Skincare', 'G. Tox', 50),
(11, 'Goop Skincare', 'Peel Pads', 100),
(12, 'Goop Skincare', 'Peel Pads', 400),
(13, 'G Label', 'Mel Jeans', 400),
(13, 'G Label', 'Nina dress', 500),
(14, 'G Label', 'Nina dress', 1000),
(15, 'G Label', 'Mel Jeans', 400),
(16, 'Goop Skincare', 'Peel Pads', 400),
(17, 'G Label', 'Alexis Skirt', 350);
```

This is the code I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT Business_unit, product_name,
SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM product_sales
GROUP BY Business_unit, product_name
ORDER BY business_unit DESC
```

How do I add in a Rank column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    Business_unit, 
    product_name,
    SUM(sales) AS sales,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) rnk
FROM product_sales
GROUP BY Business_unit, product_name
ORDER BY rnk, business_unit
```

For your sample data, [this yields](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7cd0f17bc77ea541cbf6dd5a2c472ee):

```
business_unit | product_name           | sales | rnk
:------------ | :--------------------- | ----: | --:
G Label       | Nina dress             |  1500 |   1
Goop Skincare | Peel Pads              |  1100 |   2
G Label       | Mel Jeans              |   800 |   3
G Label       | Puff Sleeve Sweatshirt |   700 |   4
Goop Skincare | Goop Glow              |   600 |   5
G Label       | Alexis Skirt           |   350 |   6
Goop Skincare | G. Tox                 |   150 |   7
```

Notes:

- `DISTINCT` in a `GROUP BY` query is superfluous, and somehow obfsucating (`DISTINCT` is aggregation in essence)
- depending on how you want to handle ties, you may also want to try `DENSE_RANK()` (or `ROW_NUMBER()`), which are the two complementary ranking functions to `RANK()`